# Button with ControlTemplate does not display in designer

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a ControlTemplate for Buttons and am having a problem - It will not draw or display in the Designer, but appears just fine at runtime. In the designer, the area where the control should be displayed is only a box the same color as the Background color.

What is going on and what do I need to do to fix it?

My ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="TechButton">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <TechControls:TagConverter x:Key="TagConverter"/>
        <TechControls:OuterEdgeConverter x:Key="OuterEdgeConverter"/>
        <TechControls:HighlightEdgeConverter x:Key="HighlightEdgeConverter" />
        <TechControls:ColorBrightness x:Key="ColorBrightnessConverter"/>
        <TechControls:TagFontConverter x:Key="TagFontConverter"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Border Name="RootElement">
        <Grid x:Name="theGrid" Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <Grid.Tag>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TagConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Tag>

            <!--Outer Edge-->
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="1"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=0 }">
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="0.85"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=1 }">
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="0.7"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=2 }">
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="0.55"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=3 }">
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="0.4"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=4 }">
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity="0.25"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=5 }">
            </Polyline>

            <!--Bottom/Right Highlights-->
            <Polyline Opacity="0.8"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource HighlightEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=0 }">
                <Polyline.Stroke>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.4"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Polyline.Stroke>
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Opacity="0.4"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource HighlightEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=1 }">
                <Polyline.Stroke>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.4"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Polyline.Stroke>
            </Polyline>

            <!--MouseOver Highlights-->
            <Polyline Opacity="0" x:Name="MouseOverHighlight"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource OuterEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=0 }">
                <Polyline.Fill>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.5"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Polyline.Fill>
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Opacity="0" x:Name="MouseOverHighlightBorder1"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource HighlightEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=0 }">
                <Polyline.Stroke>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.5"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Polyline.Stroke>
            </Polyline>
            <Polyline Opacity="0" x:Name="MouseOverHighlightBorder2"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=theGrid, Converter={StaticResource HighlightEdgeConverter}, ConverterParameter=1 }">
                <Polyline.Stroke>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.5"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Polyline.Stroke>
            </Polyline>

            <!--Inner Shape-->
            <Polyline Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Opacity=".25" StrokeThickness="2"
                          Points="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=ContentPresenter}">
            </Polyline>

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Margin="26,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentPresenter.Tag>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TagFontConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="FontFamily" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="FontStyle" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="FontWeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="FontStretch" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Path="FontSize" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ContentPresenter.Tag>
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.4"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="theGrid" Property="Margin" Value="1,1,-1,-1"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="MouseOverHighlight" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
            <Setter TargetName="MouseOverHighlightBorder1" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter TargetName="MouseOverHighlightBorder2" Property="Opacity" Value="0.6"/>
            <Setter TargetName="ContentPresenter" Property="TextBlock.Foreground">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorBrightnessConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="0.7"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

</ControlTemplate>
```

And relevant converter classes:

```
public class TagConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Size sizeVal = new Size(double.Parse(values[0].ToString()), double.Parse(values[1].ToString()));

        return sizeVal;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class TagFontConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        PointCollection r = new PointCollection();

        double ActualHeight = double.Parse(values[0].ToString());
        double ActualWidth = double.Parse(values[1].ToString());
        double Offset = double.Parse(values[2].ToString());

        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(values[3].ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface((FontFamily)values[4], (FontStyle)values[5], (FontWeight)values[6], (FontStretch)values[7]),
            (double)values[8], Brushes.Black);

        double Height = ActualHeight - 14;
        double Width = ft.Width + 14;
        if (Width < ActualWidth / 2)
            Width = ActualWidth / 2;

        int startX = 22;
        int startY = 7;

        r.Add(new Point(startX + Offset, startY + Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(startX + Width - Offset, startY + Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(startX + Width - Offset, startY + (Height / 2) - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(startX + Width - (Height / 2) - Offset, startY + Height - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(startX + Offset, startY + Height - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(startX + Offset, startY + Offset));

        return r;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class OuterEdgeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Size desiredSize = (Size)value;
        double ActualHeight = desiredSize.Height;
        double ActualWidth = desiredSize.Width;
        double DiagonalOffset = 10;
        double BaseOffset = 1;
        double AdditionalOffset = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        double Offset = BaseOffset + AdditionalOffset;

        PointCollection r = new PointCollection();

        r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, ActualHeight - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, DiagonalOffset));
        r.Add(new Point(DiagonalOffset, 0 + Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - Offset, 0 + Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - 0.5 - Offset, ActualHeight - DiagonalOffset));
        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - DiagonalOffset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));

        return r;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class HighlightEdgeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Size desiredSize = (Size)value;
        double ActualHeight = desiredSize.Height;
        double ActualWidth = desiredSize.Width;
        double DiagonalOffset = 10;
        double BaseOffset = 1;
        double AdditionalOffset = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

        double Offset = BaseOffset + AdditionalOffset;

        PointCollection r = new PointCollection();

        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - Offset, 0 + Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - 0.5 - Offset, ActualHeight - DiagonalOffset));
        r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - DiagonalOffset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));
        r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));

        return r;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class ColorBrightness : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(values[0].ToString());
        float correctionFactor = float.Parse(values[1].ToString());

        float red = (float)color.R;
        float green = (float)color.G;
        float blue = (float)color.B;

        if (correctionFactor < 0)
        {
            correctionFactor = 1 + correctionFactor;
            red *= correctionFactor;
            green *= correctionFactor;
            blue *= correctionFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            red = (255 - red) * correctionFactor + red;
            green = (255 - green) * correctionFactor + green;
            blue = (255 - blue) * correctionFactor + blue;
        }

        Color r = Color.FromArgb(color.A, (byte)red, (byte)green, (byte)blue);

        return new SolidColorBrush(r);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How it looks in the Designer:

[image]

How it looks at Runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After screwing around with this, I was able to determine that the issue is here:

```
Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

It appears that FindAncestor will not resolve in the designer, resulting in the Stroke being null for all of my drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't bind to an ancestor window, since it's not guaranteed to exist. Especially in the designer. You're making a control template for a button, so you should bind to the Foreground of the button, which will inherit from the Window or whatever container it is in. Try this:

```
Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

or

```
Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
```

Comment: Buttons do not inherit their Foreground property from their parent container. This is the reason I was trying to bind it to the Ancester window - which is something that, because I am the only one using these templates, I *can* guarantee will always exist. I was hoping to set my template up so that I would never have to manually bind or change the Foreground property of Buttons that implement it.

Comment: Yes they do. Button inherits its Foreground property from Control, which has Inherits set to true in its metadata. Window also inherits from Control, so unless the Foreground is set explicitly somewhere, the Button will inherit its Foreground from the Window.

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected: I just tested it and the button indeed doesn't inherit the Foreground of the Window. My bad...